# Read only files on WIN 10

Tags: windows-10

When I have upgraded from WIN 8.1 to WIN 10 all data files under "Documents" have become read only which makes it impossible to update or save new files.
How do i change it to normal again?

Comment: Select them all, right click them, uncheck 'Read Only'

Comment: no check, more like clear the box (no color)

Comment: Got the same copy file to desktop change name, delete original and put copy back that is what i have been doing.

Answer (score 0):

This [seems to be an issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/document-folders-marked-read-only-after-upgrade-to/4f00d3fe-82b0-4e6d-a92a-f81751aa6f51) for some people upgrading to Windows 10. This might help:

- Right-click your *Documents* folder and open its *Properties*.
- Uncheck *Read only*.
- Open the *Security* tab and click the *Edit* button below the user list (it might be labelled differently, I'm translating from a German system).
- Select your user name from the list and check all checkboxes in the left column.
- Close both windows by clicking *OK*, then check to save changes to your files again. If it fails, open the directory, select all files (Ctrl + A), right-click them and repeat these steps.